# scrollbar is not working in IE 8

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, master-page, page-layout, internet-explorer

we are having a bit of problem with the scrollbar in SharePoint 2013 in IE8. Anyone has got any where should look or what should I change?

EDIT:
We are using custom materpage, custom page layout and custom css.

Thank you.

Comment: Custom masterpage? Custom page layout? Custom CSS?

Comment: I had a similar problem caused by users using 64-bit Internet Explorer instead of 32-bit. That might be worth checking out.

Comment: @Robert Lindgren, please see my edit above.

Comment: @Aron Foster - IE is 32bit.

Comment: Then there is your problem, some of that custom css is probably messing with IE 8